# how to sum of object values in nested array in mongodb ? using Node Express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

Array look like as below, I want sum of "extra_amount" by using NodeJS and MongoDB. How to do ?

```js
    [
  {
    "extra_work": [
      {
        "extra_name": [
          {
            "0": "krunal",
            "1": "riddhi"
          }
        ],
        "extra_amount": [
          {
            "0": "100",
            "1": "100"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: this is a collection and the `{ "extra_work" ...` is a document inside the collection? or this is an array inside a document? Also if you can give us the expected results so we know what you need as result

Comment: this is an array inside a document and i want to do sum of all numbers inside extra_amount e.g 0:100, 1:100, then expected result would be 200